# JSONDecodeError after some time when scraping with scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am getting the following error:

> aise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I know this is caused at this point in my script:

> container = json.loads(response.text)

I am taking a guess here and it's because the website redirects me and I do not get a response 200. I say this because I can scrape a couple thousands of results until eventually this error keeps appearing. What marvels me is that It will sometimes still continue to grab data, so perhaps this rejects the issue being about the response. Perhaps the json is not properly loaded when scraped from the webpage?

How can I solve this issue?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from price_parser import Price
import re
from itertools import zip_longest
import pandas as pd

def get_price(price_raw):
    price_object = Price.fromstring(price_raw)
    return price_object.amount_float

def get_currency(price_raw):
    price_object = Price.fromstring(price_raw)
    currency = price_object.currency
    return currency

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.theparking.eu',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'origin': 'https://www.theparking.eu',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    #'referer': 'https://www.theparking.eu/used-cars/used-cars/',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
}

class Countryitem(scrapy.Item):
    make = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    latest_price = Field(input_processor = MapCompose(get_price),
                        output_processor = TakeFirst())
    currency = Field(input_processor = MapCompose(get_currency),
                        output_processor = TakeFirst())
    old_price = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    model = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    sub_data = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    mileage = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    transmission= Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    year = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    fuel = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    text = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    listing_date = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    location = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    postal_code = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    country = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    page_number = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())

class CountrySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "country"
    start_urls = ['https://www.theparking.eu/used-cars/used-cars/#!/used-cars/%3Fid_pays%3D87']
    #for links, pages, id, country in zip(url_data.links, url_data.pages, url_data.id, url_data.country):

    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL':'INFO',
        'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE':25,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN':24,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS':64,
        'COOKIES_ENABLED':False,
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT':15,
        #'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':5
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            for page in range(1, 1000):
                yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                    url = url,
                    method="POST",
                    callback = self.parse,
                    formdata =  {
                        'ajax': '{"tab_id":"t0","cur_page":%s,"cur_trie":"distance","query":"","critere":{"id_pays":["87"]},"sliders":{"prix":{"id":"#range_prix","face":"prix","max_counter":983615,"min":"1","max":"400000"},"km":{"id":"#range_km","face":"km","max_counter":1071165,"min":"1","max":"500000"},"millesime":{"id":"#range_millesime","face":"millesime","max_counter":1163610,"min":"1900","max":"2022"}},"req_num":1,"nb_results":"11795660","current_location_distance":-1,"logged_in":false}' % page,
                        'tabs': '["t0"]'
                        },
                    headers=headers,
                    cb_kwargs = {
                        'page_number':page
                    }
            )
    def parse(self, response,page_number):
        container = json.loads(response.text)
        test=container['#lists']
        soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'lxml')
        #test2 = soup.select("a.external.tag_f_titre > span.sub-title.title-block:nth-child(3)")
        for i in soup:
            
            sub_data = i.select("a.external.tag_f_titre > span.sub-title.title-block:nth-child(3)")
            carMake = i.select("a.external.tag_f_titre > span.title-block.brand:nth-child(1)")
            carModel = i.select("a.external.tag_f_titre > span.sub-title.title-block:nth-child(2)")
            latest_price = i.select("ul.resultat section.clearfix div div > div.price-block > p.prix")
            old_price = i.select("ul.resultat section.clearfix div div > div.price-block > p.old-prix > s")
            carMileage = i.select("ul.info.clearfix li:nth-child(2) > div.upper")
            carTransmission = i.select("li:nth-child(4) > div.upper")
            carFuel = i.select("li:nth-child(1) > div.upper")
            carYear = i.select("li:nth-child(3) > div.upper")
            carListing = i.select("div.loc-date > p.btn-publication")
            carLocation = i.select("div.location > span.upper")
            carPostal = i.select("li:nth-child(5) > div.upper")

            for make, newprice,model, subdata, mileage, oldprice, transmission, fuel, year, listing, location, postal in zip_longest(
                carMake, latest_price, carModel, sub_data, carMileage,
                old_price, carTransmission, carFuel, carYear, carListing, carLocation, carPostal
                ):
                loader = ItemLoader(Countryitem())
                loader.add_value('page_number', page_number)
                if make != None:
                    loader.add_value('make', make.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('make', "None")
                if newprice != None:
                    loader.add_value('latest_price', re.sub(" ",'',re.sub(',','',newprice.text.strip())))

                else:
                    loader.add_value('latest_price', "None")
                    
                if newprice !=None:
                    loader.add_value('currency', re.sub(" ",'',re.sub(',','',newprice.text.strip())))
                else:
                    loader.add_value('currency', "None")
   
                if oldprice != None:
                    loader.add_value('old_price', oldprice.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('old_price', "None")
                if model != None:
                    loader.add_value('model', model.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('model', "None")
                if subdata != None:
                    loader.add_value('sub_data', subdata.get_text(" "))
                else:
                    loader.add_value('sub_data', "None")

                if mileage != None:
                    loader.add_value('mileage', mileage.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('mileage', "None")
                if transmission != None:
                    loader.add_value('transmission', transmission.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('transmission', "None")
                if fuel != None:
                    loader.add_value('fuel', fuel.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('fuel', "None")
                if year != None:
                    loader.add_value('year', year.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('year', "None")
                if listing != None:
                    loader.add_value('listing_date', listing.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('listing_date', "None")
                if location != None:
                    loader.add_value('location', location.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('location', "None")
                if postal != None:
                    loader.add_value('postal_code', postal.text)
                else:
                    loader.add_value('postal_code', None)

                yield loader.load_item()
        
process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEED_URI':'park.jl',
        'FEED_FORMAT':'jsonlines'
    }
)
process.crawl(CountrySpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Usually happens when you get rate limited and the server response isn't JSON but a warning in html or text

Comment: To add to @bushcat69's comment, you can put the code `container = json.loads(response.text)` in a`try...except` block and maybe print the response when you encounter the error to check if the data is properly formatted.

Comment: @msenior_ t seems that it has sent the requests to a different url:```https://www.theparking.eu/used-cars/used-cars/?_escaped_fragment_=%2Fused-cars%2F%253Fid_pays%253D106``` is an example. This takes you right back into the main page, therefore it won't process the json as the `payloads` differ. It has somehow been redirected even though scrapy does not make any mention of a redirect. Which probably explains why it still scrapes after some pages.

Comment: like @bushcat69 mentions, I am likely getting rate-limited. I have checked up to page 83 and get ```Caught exception: searchd error: per-query max_matches=2025 out of bounds (per-server max_matches=2000)``` from the url.